# Cannot get "Generate Database from Model" using "Migration T-SQL" approach in VS2012/EF5. Is this a bug??? Works fine in VS2010

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I have got a tricky problem with VS2012 and EF5. I have posted the full details on the MSDN forum, see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c63bf034-f205-4b4e-82e0-40b1c3fca71d.

However it seems that the EF team are now recommending we also post on here as well, so I am.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the EF Designer Power Pack then it is not supported. See this for more details: 
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/499

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I have now tried to raise this with Microsoft. Thanks.